How to have two identical windows in SDL2?
In my app I draw things and put sprites on a renderer, and I need to have two windows that show the exact same thing, from this renderer.
Is there a way I can do that ?
I tried things such as reading pixels from a renderer to put them in another texture tied to the other renderer for the other window, and the function SDL_CreateWindowFrom(), which caused a crash (BadWindow error)

Could you create 2 separate windows and renderers and then write a wrapper around SDL_RenderCopy which takes 2 renderers and invokes that function twice?

The problem is that textures are tied to only one renderer so they can't be copied to other renderers. And loading every sprite twice just for that is also not an option
